# Laravel: Multiple count for different tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, count

I have three different eloquent query for get count of my tables.

```
$posts = Post::where('published', true)->count();
$pages = Pages::where('published', true)->count();
$products = Product::where('published', true)->count();
```

There is a way for have an unique Eloquent query? (If is possible, I'd like don't use DB::raw).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Write your code like in single query.**

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE published = true) as post_count, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages WHERE published = true) as page_count, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE published = true) as product_count");
```

After that you can get record like

```
$data->post_count
$data->page_count
$data->product_count
```

Comment: Is this query safe from sql injection? thanks

Comment: Yes its safe...